# How to "save for web" multiple Illustrator files with Illustrator script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, illustrator-scripting

I have about 55 ai files and i wanted to save for web for all these files using adobe illustrator script. I wanted to save all of them at 1200 percent size of the document size.

Answer (score 1):

The logic for what your script does is like this:

1. open the group of files and make a list of their file system locations
2. loop through the files in the list one at a time:

   1. open one document in Illustrator
   2. increase the artwork size to 1200%
   3. Save for Web
   4. close the document without saving
   5. repeat

With AppleScript, you would write a pattern like this:

```
on open theFiles
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        tell application "Illustrator"
            open theFile
            -- increase artwork size to 1200% step goes here
            -- Save for Web step goes here
            close the front document saving no
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

… and then Save that AppleScript as an app. To use the app, you would just drop your group of files onto it.

Comment: please also write this code